# Is the United States the first country to restrict the purchase of home and land of individuals from a certain country country-wide or not?

Tags: united-states, international

https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/news/florida-gov-ron-desantis-introduces-183632318.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8

> About the portal: The portal, which comes as part of a law signed in
> May, **aims to restrict individuals from countries perceived as U.S.
> enemies from purchasing homes and land. The legislation prohibits
> those affiliated with the People’s Republic of China or the Chinese
> Communist Party from acquiring property and mandates the registration
> of all owned property in Florida.**

Is the United States the first country to restrict the purchase of home and land of individuals from a certain country country-wide or not? Is there a precedent for this? I am guessing that a long time ago there might have been some laws like that, like before the 70s, but I am thinking in recent years a law like that would have been frowned upon and criticized by the international community.

Comment: The question is poorly worded. This is a Florida-only law, thus not a restriction by the United States.

Comment: A lot of countries limit who can buy land based on citizenship. https://realting.com/news/where-it-is-banned-or-hard-for-foreigners-to-buy-real-estate

Comment: For my the actual question would be if this is constitutional, in the sense that it might be considered as "foreign policy", which is an exclusive competence of the Federal government.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted?

Comment: i am not the downwoter, but it seems a tad too broad

Comment: I'd like to think it was downvoted for not showing any research effort. But nobody seems to care about such basic SE rules here.

Comment: Again, this is not a restriction **by the United States**, but by individual states. "Heading into 2023, 14 states had laws restricting foreign ownership or investments in private agricultural land. So far this year, restrictive laws also have been enacted in Arkansas, Idaho, Montana, Tennessee, Utah and Virginia."  -- [APNews](https://apnews.com/article/florida-chinese-citizens-property-law-4aeecc7a9470d03726658f1ef7b1d1f1) The Florida law is somewhat more restrictive than those of other states.

Comment: First this isn’t a restriction by the United States just a state level restriction and second a quick google search shows plenty of other countries and states have similar restrictions.

Comment: Summary [link from US State Departmen](https://www.state.gov/reports/2023-investment-climate-statements/).  Someone with more time can dig through the underlying pages that can be selected from there with summaries regarding foreign investment and ownership in many countries...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just two examples:

- Denmark: Foreign citizen require case-by-case approval.
- Poland: Foreign citizens need case-by-case approval. National security is explicitly mentioned as one consideration.

Comment: The question isn't very clear but I'd read it as asking about cases where this restriction was on specific countries, in the case above its those from or affiliated with China, whereas your examples are a blanket all-foreign citizens regardless of country.

Comment: @LioElbammalf Technically true but if they write case-by-case and cite national security as a reason you can be sure there will be a very distinct country pattern with some countries being almost always allowed and others almost always forbidden to purchase.

Comment: @LioElbammalf yeah, specific "bad countries" lists are not so common, but the opposite--"good/friend countries"  list--is more common. E.g. in several EU countries the restrictions don't apply to other EU citizens, Saudi Arabia has bilateral understandings in that regard with some other Gulf countries etc. https://tile.loc.gov/storage-services/service/ll/llglrd/2023555905/2023555905.pdf